# log-probit model: Calculation of confidence intervals for ED50 data

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, logit, probit

I calculate log-probit models according to the following method (many thanks to COOLSerdash, Aniko, whuber):

```
# data: textbook from Erna Weber
dosis <- c(2.90, 3.36, 3.90, 4.52, 5.52, 6.09,6.90)
nges <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10)
nok <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 8)
edx.data <- data.frame(dosis, nges, nok)

# glm
glm.logit <- glm(cbind(nok,nges-nok) ~ log(dosis), family=binomial('probit'), data=edx.data)

# calculation of EDx data and confidence intervals
r <- dose.p(glm.logit,p=seq(0.1,0.9,0.2))
se <- attr(r,'SE')
xr <- data.frame(as.matrix(exp(r)))
names(xr) <- c('Dose')
xr$Lower <- exp(r-se) 
xr$Upper <- exp(r+se)
```

The output is as follows:

```
> print(xr)
             Dose    Lower     Upper
p = 0.1: 2.827593 2.444115  3.271238
p = 0.3: 3.920316 3.606605  4.261315
p = 0.5: 4.915905 4.576043  5.281009
p = 0.7: 6.164330 5.580168  6.809647
p = 0.9: 8.546535 7.219686 10.117236
```

EDx data ("Dose") are according to the textbook by E. Weber. However, confidence intervals should be as follows:

```
  p   ED(p)   lower    upper
0.1  2.8272  1.6574   3.4642
0.3  3.9203  3.0380   4.5064
0.5  4.9159  4.2478   5.8820
0.7  6.1643  5.2973   8.6082
0.9  8.5476  6.7830  16.0300
```

The question is: where is my mistake? How to calculate these confidence intervals?

Comment: 1. Please give the full reference for the book by Erna Weber. 2. At what level do you want to calculate the confidence interval? 95%? Because now, you only add and subtract 1 standard error from the estimate whereas for a 95%-CI, it should be something like `exp(r-1.96*se)`. 3. How were the estimates in the book obtained? By a generalized linear model, like you did?

Comment: @COOLSerdash: The reference is E.WEBER: Grundriss der biologischen Statistik. Anwendung der mathematischen Statistik in Forschung, Lehre und Praxis. Jena, VEB Gustav Fischer Verlag, 1967, and originally published by D.J.FINNEY: Probit Analysis. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1971 (3. edition). 95 % is correct - I am going to try out your suggestion. Both books describe the original log-probit method as introduced by Finney.

Comment: @COOLSerdash: I used exp(r-1.96*se) but the conf. interval is still smaller than that from Weber: e. g. p = 0.9: 8.546535 6.140128 11.896051.

Comment: I know, I tried it myself. How are the confidence intervals calculated in the book?

Comment: I have a report that contains these equation (written by myself a lot of years ago) - can I upload this? And how?

Comment: Thanks Christian. You could upload a picture at http://imgur.com/, for example and post the link here. Then, I could upload the picture into your question. It would be very helpful to know how the ED50 and the confidence intervals were estimated.

Comment: Thank you! But I just found a R script that exactly calculates Finney's (and Weber's) conf. intervals: http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchSingleRepresentation.action?uri=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0054092.s004 (paper: same address without '.s004')

Comment: For those that are interested I recently created a package in R, 'ecotox', that calculates LCs and LTs using formulas from D.J. Finney's 1971 book on probit analysis. The package is downloadable from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecotox/index.html) or the developer version is on [github](https://github.com/benjaminhlina/ecotox).

Answer (score 1):

I just found a R script that exactly calculates Finney's confidence intervals. This paper can be found [here](http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchSingleRepresentation.action?uri=info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0054092). The R code is found [here](http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchSingleRepresentation.action?uri=info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0054092.s004). The underlying statistical derivation can be found in D.J.FINNEY: Probit Analysis. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1971, 3. edition. In addition, it might be of interest that with SAS and SPSS one get confidence intervals according to Finney (own comparison using two examples).

Comment: Welcome to our site, Christian, and thank you for doing that research!  Would you mind adding a line or two to your answer that clarifies why the two sets of confidence intervals disagree? That will be especially helpful to future readers when (possibly) the links you have provided might no longer be available.

Comment: It was only possible to add the reference that contains this rather long derivation - two lines are not enough to explain the differences. (And this would also be a little bit beyond my knowledge of such calculations.)